# Can I check if an element has changed using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm assigning a variable like this

```
question = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'QuestionModal'))).text
```

This element is changing over time and when it does I want to save the new changed element's text.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element

Comment: What is the changed value and original value  ?

Comment: There are quiz questions. Like 'How many sec is a minute?' etc.
And the question is changing if we choose an answer.